# QPushButton in Qt designer

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer

[image: image of my button]

How can I remove this dark area from my QPush Button in checked mode?
button is flat

Comment: I have a really difficult time to find a solution to your problem. Would you like to share more details?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the background color, and the border of the button, you can use style sheet like this:

```
auto button = new QPushButton;
button->setCheckable(true);
button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton:checked"
                      "{"
                      "    background-color: transparent;"
                      "    border: none;"
                      "}");
```